# Quick sort, maximum stack call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, quicksort

What is wrong with my algorithm. Is it a limitation of hardware, I am on an old computer, or is my code that is not right? The algorithm worked fined for a vector wit 3.5 thousands objects. Now I am getting maximum call stack error when using a 85 thousand object vector. I tried to find the error but I couldn't find it.

```
import { gastos } from './cota-parlamentar-282-mil.mjs';

function quickSort2(vetor, listaPropriedadesOrdenacao) {


    quickSort(vetor, listaPropriedadesOrdenacao[0]);


}

function quickSort(vetor, propriedadeOrdenacao, ini = 0, fim = vetor.length - 1) {

    if (fim > ini) {
        const pivot = fim;

        let div = ini - 1;

        for (let i = ini; i < fim; i++) {


          //I order the array based on the property specified
            if (vetor[i][propriedadeOrdenacao] < vetor[pivot][propriedadeOrdenacao]) {

                div++
                if (i !== div) {
                    [vetor[i], vetor[div]] = [vetor[div], vetor[i]]
                }

            }
        }
        div++

        if (vetor[pivot][propriedadeOrdenacao] < vetor[div][propriedadeOrdenacao]) {

            [vetor[pivot], vetor[div]] = [vetor[div], vetor[pivot]]


        }



        quickSort(vetor, propriedadeOrdenacao, ini, div - 1)

      //I am getting the error with the line below
        quickSort(vetor, propriedadeOrdenacao, div + 1, fim)



    }
}



quickSort2(gastos, ['partido', 'nome_parlamentar', 'id_documento']);
```

Excuse me for the naming covention and stuff I am just prototyping.

Comment: You're choosing the pivot as the last element in range, so you have worst-case behaviour when the list is already sorted or nearly sorted. Not surprising this exhibits as a stack overflow. If you are using this for a real project rather than just learning about sorting algorithms, then you should just use the built-in sorting function. If it's an academic exercise but you still want to sort lists of 85k elements, choose the pivot randomly.

Comment: I increased node maximum call with the command node --stack-size=10000 scriptname.js. I called it with 280 thousands I worked just fine!

Comment: The worst-case behaviour will require a stack depth of the same magnitude as the size of the list.

Comment: Can you include the code that defines gastos? The quicksort function should take ini and fim as parameters, not define them. Those parameters should be defined in the function that calls quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough code in the question to test, but try these changes:

```
    quickSort(vetor, listaPropriedadesOrdenacao[0], 0, vetor.length - 1);

...

function quickSort(vetor, propriedadeOrdenacao, ini, fim) {
    while (fim > ini) {
    ...
        if((div - ini) < (fim - div)){
            quickSort(vetor, propriedadeOrdenacao, ini, div - 1)
            ini = div + 1
        } else {
            quickSort(vetor, propriedadeOrdenacao, div + 1, fim)
            fim = div - 1
        }
```